# how to get value from href in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following url of my html page, and I am looking for a way to get the value "1997" passed into a string using javascript.

I am thinking of using Regex, but isn't there a much simpler way?

```
http://localhost:8080/App/sample?proj=1997
```

Comment: Does that number always gonna be the value of `proj`?

Comment: Yes, it will always be the value of proj

Comment: Just split the string

Comment: `url.split('proj=')[1] || null`

Comment: `new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('proj')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick function using [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and a `for` loop.

```js
function getParam (url, param) {
  try {
    /* Get the parameters. */
    var params = url.split("?")[1].split("&");

    /* Iterate over each parameter. */
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
      /* Split the string to a key-value pair */
      var pair = params[i].split("=");

      /* Check whether the param given matches the one iterated. */
      if (pair[0] == param) return pair[1];  
    }
  } catch (e) {}
  
  /* Return null, if there is no match. */
  return null;
}

/* Example. */
console.log(
  getParam("http://localhost/dir/file", "proj"),
  getParam("http://localhost:8080/App/sample?proj=1997", "proj")
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I found this
=
new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('proj')
To be easier

Comment: You're welcome @PedroMartins. Beware that [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams) for `URLSearchParams` isn't all that great yet *(~85%)*.

Comment: Oh okay, good to know then.
But I need it for just a simple case. So won't be a problem.